# How to get id from table on criterium from other MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with sql query.
I have 2 tables Rooms (Id_room, Name) and Room_list (id, id_room, datafrom, dateto) and two variables date1 and date2. I need to get the ID_room's from Rooms that is not used in Room_list with dates between date1 and date2. 
I hope You can help me couse i have no idea how to get this

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Looks like a good case for `JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a left join

```
$stmt = "SELECT *
FROM Rooms
LEFT JOIN Rooms_list ON Rooms.id_room=Room_list.id_room
WHERE Rooms_list.datefrom>='".$date1."'
AND Rooms_list.dateto<='".$date2."'";
```